# Need to remove gray shadow from borders of header in WP theme

Tags: css, header, border, shadow

Using WP there is a gray shadow on either side of the page header and I cannot find any way to remove it.
[image: see faint gray as highlighted in red brackets please]

I've tried disabling the css box shadow but to no avail:

```html
#wrapper, .container, #container, .banner headerclass, .wrap contentclass, #row, #header, header {
    border: 0px red solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: here is the current page: https://www.oceanangle.com/  And tried the shot-gun to apply the box-shadow parameter to every element thus my elongated string of connectors.

Comment: Eureka!  That was it, problem solved!  Thank you AStombaugh - please submit this as the solution and I will mark this closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.boxed #wrapper.container {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.16)!important
}
```

The top-level `<div>` with the `boxed` class is the one containing the box-shadow you don't want. You can also search for style attributes in the browser inspector if you ever get stuck and can't figure out where an attribute is being applied.

Comment: Thank you again AStombaugh - getting back to your recommendation using the browser inspector - I DID locate the div: <div id="wrapper" class="container"> but did not see where the .boxed class was applied to this element.  If you would, please clarify for me how to identify - many thanks again!